# Как получить путь к картинке с заданными размерами? WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Вот код вывода блока с фоновой картинкой

```
if(!empty($project_miniature_bg_image)) {
    // $project_miniature_bg_image - это id изображения
    $thumb_bg = '<div class="thumb_bg bg_img" style="background-image: url('. wp_get_attachment_image_src( $project_miniature_bg_image, "project_miniature" ).')"></div>';
    echo $thumb_bg;
}
```

Вот код из functions.php

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'project_miniature', 900, 900, true );
}
```

В инспекторе отображается вот так

```
<div class="thumb_bg bg_img" style="background-image: url(Array)"></div>
```

Нужно получить путь к картинке и с заданными размерами. Как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_get_attachment_image_src` возвращает массив данных об изображении,  если вам нужна только ссылка то можно сделать вот так

```
if( ! empty( $project_miniature_bg_image ) ) :
    ?>

    <div class="thumb_bg bg_img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $project_miniature_bg_image, "project_miniature" ); ?>)"></div>';
    
    <?php
endif;
```

Comment: <div class="thumb_bg bg_img" style="background-image: url(http://localhost/ant_studio/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/img_03.jpg)"></div>   Вот так получается, то есть нет четких размеров по "project_miniature"

Comment: значит у этого изображения нет данного размера

Comment: Да это правильно, оно такое и с макета скопировано ))))

Comment: Спасибо!!! ))))))))

Comment: если ответ был полезен вы можете отметить его и изменин статус вопроса на решен